# Removing frontend dependancies from WordPress Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to make my theme totally independent of ACF's `get_field` and `the_field` (so in case the plugin is disabled the site will not break). I have an image that is loaded via custom field `'slider_image'` as an inline `background-image`. I need to call the URL of the image. Is it possible to load this into inlined html? Here's the working code (w/ ACF's `the_field`):

```
    <!-- Hero Image -->
    <section class="hero" style="background: url('<?php the_field('slider_image'); ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
    </section>
    <!-- End Hero Image -->
```

How can I use `get_post_meta` to rewrite this statement in case the plugin is disabled?

I've tried:

```
<section class="hero" style="background: url('<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slider_image', true ); ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
```

Which returns:

```
<section class="hero" style="background: url('98') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be the id of the post for attached image. To grab current image you must use some of the embedded WP functions like [wp_get_attachment_image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) (if you want to print image tag) or [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) (if you want image attributes)

For example in your case, when you want only `url` of the image you can do something like this:

```
$img_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slider_image', true );
$image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, 'large' ); //returns false or array
if ( $image_attr ) {
    $img_url = $image_attr[0]; ?>
    <section class="hero" style="background: url('<?php echo $img_url; ?>') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
<?php } ?>
```